# Singly linked list in java implementation

Tags: java

Hello I'm implementing a singly linked list, without using the library one. I'm encounting problems on adding an element at the end of the list. Can anyone help me please. Here is my code:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> implements GenericLinkedList<T> {
        private Node<T> head;
        private Node<T> tail;
        private int size;

        public SinglyLinkedList() {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            size = 0;
                }
            public void addLast(T elem) {
            tail.next.element  = elem;
            size++;
        }

**public void addLast(T elem) {
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
            tail.next = null;
            newNode.element = elem;

        **
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: looks like you're going to get a NullPointerException. Why didn't you tell us that?

Comment: Also, think about the pre/post conditions for `addLast`. before hand, tail must be pointing to the last element(so by definition next is null). Afterwards, tail should be the element you added (as it's the new end)

Answer (score 2):

You specify the tail's next element, but you should also consider that the inserted element becomes the new tail itself. In short:

1. Create a new node.
2. Store the element on it.
3. Make the tail point to that node. (the current tail becomes, then, the `nth - 1` element).
4. Make the newly inserted element your new tail.
5. Increment the list's size.

Your current problem is also related to steps 1 and 3. You don't define a `Node` object to store and `tail.next` should be null if it is truly the tail of the list.

Comment: Not just that, but the OP also isn't doing step 1. That's the most basic error: before anything else, they must allocate storage for the new element.

Comment: @DanielMartin Indeed. That's why I included step 1, but it's a good clarification to point at to.

Comment: I have updated the question, but I don't know how to add that new node to the list

Comment: @jojuk You almost got it, but you're missing some key aspects. Adding the node to the list is actually making `tail.next = newNode` and then `tail = newNode`. You're having a hard time defining object references.

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem. Thanks for the advices

Answer (score 1):

here is full code of singlylinkedlist.
**SinglyLinkedList**

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private Node<T> temp;
    private int size;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void addLast(T elem) {
        if(head == null){
            head = new Node<T>();
            head.element = elem;
            tail = head;
            size++;
        } else  {
            temp = new Node<T>();
            temp.element = elem;
            tail.next = temp;
            temp.prev = tail;
            tail = temp;
            size++;
        }  

    }
    void print(){
        temp = head;
        while(temp  != null){
            System.out.println(temp.element);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
        list.addLast(1);
        list.addLast(2);
        list.addLast(3);
        list.addLast(4);
        list.addLast(5);
        list.addLast(6);
        list.print();

    }
}
```

**Node**

```
public class Node<T>{
    Node<T> prev;
    Node<T> next;
    T element;
    public Node() {
    }
}
```